# How to read data of MSI file that contains encrypted JSON data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-installer

I did an application, in that I have stored all the data in mySQL database. Now, I will download a MSI file that contains user relevant data on successful user login. And I would like to read that data and display information on web page. What technologies should I use? How can I do that? Share your ideas. Finally, I use angularjs after getting the data from MSI file.

Comment: You mean you want to access the data from desktop in web app?

Comment: Yes, I will access the data from file in storage. What technologies should i use?

Comment: The reason why your question has not got answers yet, is that your task contains several steps which are moreoever not related and not very clear (reading a MSI file locally, display information in web, what has first task to do with Angular or web- probably nothing, why you mention encryption, we can not help you there). Please tell, if question is still open for you.
There exist of course standard mechanisms in reading the content (tables) out of a msi file, but this works of course only locally on a Windows system with a (previously) downloaded file.